# Python call function on dictionary member key change

Tags: python, observer-pattern

I have a class that looks kind of like this:

```
class MyClass:
    _properties: Dict[str, Any]

    @property
    def properties(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        ...
```

What I want to happen is I want to be notified when the dictionary is changed. So when a user does this:

```
obj = MyClass()

obj.properties['optimization'] = '-O3'
```

I would like some callback function to be called, ideally a callback function that has access to the key and value that were created/modified.

The only thing I can think of is inheriting `dict` and overriding `__setitem__`, but I am wondering if there is a nicer way to do this.

Comment: IMO inheriting `dict` as a `NotifierDict` is a clean way to do it. What exactly don't you like about that idea?

Comment: You might elect to inherit [collections.UserDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict) if you do not want to inherit `dict`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a subclass that does what you want:

```
class MyClass:
    class Properties(dict):
        def __setitem__(self, key, value):
            print("Key {} was set to {}".format(key, value))
            super().__setitem__(key, value)

    _properties = Properties()

    @property
    def properties(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return self._properties


m = MyClass()
m.properties['a'] = 12
print(m.properties)
```

output is:

```
Key a was set to 12
{'a': 12}
```